# An issue with the sequence of datetime column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

After concatenating many files into one big file, the sequence of the datetime column did not follow the original files.

I have many .csv files of meteorological data. One day one file. Interval 5 minutes. The original files use this datetime format: 24.03.2016 18:35.

I concatenatedd all files using:

```
    globbed_files = glob.glob(path + "\*Raw2*.csv")
    data = []

    for csv in globbed_files:
       df = pd.read_csv(csv, encoding = "ISO-8859-1", header = 0, 
       low_memory=False)
       data.append(df) 

    combined = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True, sort=True)
    combined['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(combined['DateTime'])
    combined.set_index('DateTime', inplace=True)
    combined.index = combined.index.map(lambda t: t.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))

    combined.to_csv(path + "\year1.txt", sep='\t', header=True, index=True)
```

The results were three files. Each file contains data from a specific year. I checked the sequence of datetime was correct for all files according to the original files.

Because I don't know how to convert the original datetime format into a DateTime format that Python can understand, I did it manually. I copied datetime column into Notepad, add second (:00), remove unnecessary spaced, replace all '.' with '/', anf finaly copy-pasted it back into csv. To make sure, on csv, again I use the ecxel bult-in date format for datetime column. The new datetime format is: 24/03/2016 18:35:00.

Next, with the new datetime format, I concatenated the 'yearly file' into a final big file.

But what happened? Python read the datetime inconsistency by exchanging date and month. So, 08/03/2016 18:35:00 can be read wrongly as month 8 and day 3 or correctly as day 8 month 3. Now, my new file is not sorted according to the original file.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution should be simplify for added parameters to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), last convert index to custom format by [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
globbed_files = glob.glob(path + "\*Raw2*.csv")
data = []

for csv in globbed_files:
   df = pd.read_csv(csv, 
                    encoding = "ISO-8859-1", 
                    header = 0, 
                    low_memory=False,
                    parse_dates=['DateTime'], #convert column to datetimes
                    dayfirst=True,  #avoid inconsistency  for specify first value is day
                    index_col=['DateTime'] #create DatetimeIndex
                    )
   data.append(df) 

combined = pd.concat(data, sort=True)

combined.index = combined.index.strftime.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

combined.to_csv(path + "\year1.txt", sep='\t', header=True, index=True)
```

Comment: you save my time. thanks. your code works, but I must remove the 2nd last line due to error here.